# Windows Batch File - Split string with certain characters or spaces as delimiter

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, whitespace

I am trying to split the entries in text files, which are in the format:

```
"C:\Software\New folder\New folder\New folder\New folder\OneDrive - Test   "
"C:\Software\New folder\New folder\New folder\New folder\OneDrive - Test  "
"C:\Software\New folder\New folder\New folder\New folder\OneDrive - Test     "
```

using quotes to show the spaces in the code above. In simple words, my text always ends with two spaces or more.

So I want to delimiter to be , (yes two spaces) so my final output should be

```
"C:\Software\New folder\New folder\New folder\New folder\OneDrive - Test"
```

using quotes to show the spaces

Alternatively, I also know that the final words in the string are always `One Drive - Test`

And even if I could split the output in the format below, I could then append to each line with `One Drive - Test`

```
"C:\Software\New folder\New folder\New folder\New folder"
```

Thank you guys, really getting tired of Batch.

Comment: check the the trim right function - http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.TrimRightFOR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to split strings at a certain delimiter character. Since you have two characters that mark a single delimiter (namely two <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>), you could replace these by a single character that cannot occur elsewhere in the string; for example, the `|` could be used as it is not allowed in file paths/names. This is how it may look like:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Read input text file `txtfile.txt` line by line:
for /F "usebackq delims= eol=|" %%L in ("textfile.txt") do (
    rem // Store line string in environment variable:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid loss of/trouble with exclamation marks:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Replace two-character delimiter by a single character:
    rem    (the `|| endlocal` suffix is only executed in case the current line contains
    rem    delimiters only, because the `for /F` loop would not execute in that case) */
    (for /F "delims=| eol=|" %%F in ("!LINE:  =|!") do (
        rem // Toggle back delayed expansion:
        endlocal
        rem /* Return part before first delimiter (actually this returns the very first
        rem    non-empty sub-string before the first (sequence of) delimiter(s), or,
        rem    if the string begins with (a) delimiter(s), the very first non-empty
        rem    sub-string between the first and second (sequences of) delimiters: */
        echo/%%F
    )) || endlocal
)

endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

If all your lines follow the shown pattern then, instead of trying to deal with strings, you can deal with file references

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem For each line in input file
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("inputFile.txt") do (
        rem Retrieve the parent folder of the read reference
        for %%b in ("%%~dpa.") do (
            rem And echo it without the ending backslash (see the dot in the upper line)
            echo %%~fb
        )
    )
```

`%%a` will hold each of the read lines while iterating over the input file

`%%~dpa` is the drive and path of the element referenced in `%%a` with an ending backslash

By adding a `.` to the previous path and retrieving its full path, we remove the ending backslash (unless the path is the root of a drive)

To save the processed lines, you only need to redirect the output

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    >"outputFile.txt" (
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("inputFile.txt") do (
            for %%b in ("%%~dpa.") do echo %%~fb
        )
    )
```